# Javascript shorthand which calls functions

Tags: javascript

I want a shorthand that runs a function if true and runs a separate function if false. Something like:

```
(condition)? function1:function2;
```

Comment: Something shorter than `condition ? function1() : function2()` ?

Comment: Something like `c ? f1() : f2()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
condition? function1():function2();
```

```js
function a() {
  return "a";
}
function b() {
  return "b";
}

(1 == 2) ? alert(a()) : alert(b());
```